# How can I solve $2x+\sqrt {10} \equiv 10 \pmod{13}?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have seen such problem:

> Find the value of  $x$:
>   $$2x+\sqrt {10} \equiv 10 \pmod{13}.$$

I think, this problem is wrong, isn't it?

$$\frac {2x+\sqrt{10}-10}{13} \in\mathbb{Z^{+}}.$$

I do not understood, what will I do with $\sqrt{10}$?

Comment: $\sqrt{10}=x$ modulo $13$ means $x^2\equiv 10\bmod 13$, so $x$ is an integer.

Comment: $\sqrt{10}=6\pmod{13}$ since $6^2=36=2\cdot 13+10$. You get that $x=2$ is your solution.

Comment: @YAlexandrov or 7.

Comment: $\sqrt{10}=7\bmod 13$, since $7^2=49=3\cdot 13+10$.

Comment: $10$ is indeed a quadratic residue modulo $13$ since,  $$\left(\dfrac{10}{13}\right)=\left(\dfrac{-3}{13}\right)=\left(\dfrac{-1}{13}\right)\left(\dfrac{3}{13}\right)=\left(\dfrac{13}{3}\right)=\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)=1$$

Comment: Again I didn't understand..:( Can you explain me, this problem without $\mod$ operator, please..

Comment: @PrasunBiswas somebody is showing off their possibly newly aquired knowledge of legendre symbol ;)

Comment: @rsadhvika, I don't get what you mean by "showing off", quadratic reciprocity is one of the basic concepts in elementary number theory. How would you know otherwise whether $\sqrt{10}$ is defined in $\Bbb Z_{13}$ or not?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas just kidding ;) Existence of a square root is not guaranteed, so I also think that checking for the existence is generally a good idea. But 13 is so small that using quadratic reciprocity here seemed a bit out of place haha

Comment: @rsadhvika, though you're right that it's easier to just check the squares modulo $13$ (they are $0,1,4,9,3,12,10$ with $(\pm 6)^2\equiv_{13} 10$), why brute-force when there's a shorter argument? ;)

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I understand the symbol $\sqrt{\cdot}$ as denoting the principal square root, which is $6=2^5$, with $5<(13-1)/2$, while $-\sqrt{10}$ would be $-6=7$. Just like on the reals $\sqrt{10}$ denotes the positive solution of $x^2=10$ and $-\sqrt{10}$ the negative.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of $\sqrt{10}\bmod 13$ is an integer $x$ with $x^2\equiv 10\bmod 13$, or $x^2-10=0$ in the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{13}$. This polynomial has $2$ solutions in this field, namely,
$$
x^2-10=(x+6)(x+7)=0.
$$
So there are two solutions for $\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: First time I saw such equation..$x^2-10=(x- \sqrt {10})(x+\sqrt {10})?$

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. according your definition $x \equiv \sqrt{10} \mod 13 ≠ \frac{x - \sqrt{10}}{13} \in \mathbb {Z^{+}}$ Am I right??

Comment: Note to the OP (@User184613): On the reals $\sqrt{10}$ denotes the *positive* solution of $x^2-10=0$, the *principal square root*. In modular arithmetic there is also the notion of principal square root and $\sqrt{10}$ would denote only that root $6$, while $-\sqrt{10}$ would denote $-6=7$. You should check the source of your exercise to see what definitions they are using.

Comment: @YAlexandrov Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @User184613 $\pmod{13}$ you can write it as $\,0 \equiv x^2-10 \color{red}{- 2 \cdot 13} \equiv x^2-36 \equiv (x-6)(x+6)\,$.